# How to autorun a java file on WildFly

Tags: java, web, web-deployment, java-ee-8

I'm developing a web app in JEE technology with WildFly as production server. Il must make some tasks **autorun** every day for performing somes operations in the databases. 
But I've never do it before with JEE technology. If someone could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to ask a specific question based on your own attempt to solve this task. Note that the community here doesn't replace other great online resources such as tutorials. Take at look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to better understand what kind of questions are to be asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a task/job which needs to run on every day as per schedule. I would suggest you consider the following options.

**Database Events / Triggers**:
Seems you have highlighted that you need some database operations right so my option is Event / Triggers where you can define the operations and schedule that when do you want run the task.

**Quartz**:
My second option is quartz schedular where you can configure your existing java Class or Servlets to run as per the time which you set in the Quartz configuration.

**Java Thread Executor**:
We can achieve your spec by using java thread itself where you can use Java Thread Executor Framework which provides many options and flexibility than traditional java. Anyhow, I'm recommending to use either option 1 or 2 consider it as the last case since we should maintain at least a thread to be live forever.

Note: I have just given the redirection to proceed so please go ahead and explore the concepts and pick the right one based on the cons and props of the approaches also suite to your spec.

Refer: the points discussed [here](https://medium.com/@ganesa_vijayakumar/the-best-ways-to-implement-an-audit-and-its-pros-and-cons-b28c1042541).There are few things related to your spec covered